# Which Python lib to use for classify data without training any model?

Tags: python, classification, few-shot-learning, zero-shot-learning

I want to classify data without training any model (nor using neural networks?), Should I use [scikit-learn](/questions/tagged/scikit-learn) or [scipy](/questions/tagged/scipy)?

There are also others like [pytorch](/questions/tagged/pytorch) or [keras](/questions/tagged/keras) that also have the classify method. Which one to choose and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are going to achieve is possible with recent advances in:

- [**zero-shot learning**](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2022/02/classification-without-training-data-zero-shot-learning-approach/) and **few-shot learning** can let you build your classifier with little or no training data.:

However note about:

- [ethics](/questions/tagged/ethics) issue [ref](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/412239/240550)
- > *"... then any attempt to identify the class(es) in the test data will be subject to extremely large amounts of uncertainty. "* [ref](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/412319/240550)